# Facebook Marketing API sandbox mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to create adverts on the Facebook using marketing (ads) API, but after some rejected requests my account has been blocked. So, I tried to find out ways to testing my API requests via sandbox mode.
Could you give me some tips about best practices of the creating adverts, campaigns and adsets on using facebook marketing (ads) API with sandbox accounts

Answer (score 3):

- Enable Account from *[FB Dev](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)->Marketing API->Tools->Sandbox Ad
  Account Management*. Get Access Token from here.
- Go to [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). Provide your Access Token
- Create campaign/adset/ad using POST request. (Find api reference [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/v2.10))
- Fetch data using GET request (check api ref)

I have worked this way. May be its not best practice, i couldn't find such thing in fb dev site,

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need to get a sandbox account, you can go to `developers.facebook.com` and get your account id, token, etc.

There are no best practices as such, you can do anything with this ad account. Just remember they have fake data, which may or may not match the real world expectations. When reading insights, you might also get empty for most of the fields.

As far as creation is concerned there shouldn't be any problem.