# testing facebook business account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-test-users

Currently I am in the development phase of a Facebook marketing API integrated app with which I want to access other business's account.

In this process, I first started with testing the application over my own business and everything is working fine however for the next bit I would like to simulate the access to another "dummy" business to make sure everything will work fine.

Knowing the above, I created a test user in the Facebook application and I was trying to create a dummy business with it however Facebook doesn't allow this since the testing user always belongs to my own business.

To cut it short, how may I create a mock or "dummy" business account which has a different business id than my own and contact the API through that?

Comment: Do you already have seen [this article](https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/v2/2016/10/19/sandbox-ad-accounts/)? Also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463487/facebook-marketing-api-sandbox-mode?rq=1

Comment: @Matteo true yes, this is the way I can test the ad creation and so forth however this is how I would test ads for MY OWN business , what I would like to do is have this for other businesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using a [Sandbox account](https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/v2/2016/10/19/sandbox-ad-accounts/). It works almost exactally like a normal business account, but with no money spent, and it's only accesable throug API.

You can enable the Sandbox account by folowing these steps:

- Go to https://developers.facebook.com/
- Click the My Apps dropdown
- Choose an app that you have Administrator or Developer Access to
- Select Marketing API. If you don't see this option, click + Add Product and add Marketing API
- Select Tools under Marketing API
- Sandbox Mode appears